# Using a Proxy Before Reading XML

Tags: c#, xml, proxy, rss

In trying to get back into C#.NET and WPF, I've been following [this RSS Reader Demo](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/34745-creating-your-own-rss-reader-in-c%23/). I understand what is going on with the code, but am getting a proxy error when doing the following line of code:

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(Url))
```

My assumption is that I need to set this request to use the default browser proxy (IWebProxy) to pass in the default values. Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Please can show me the complete error message

Comment: Maybe this article will be of some use to you : http://bit.ly/9nBvhI

Comment: @darkey Thanks for the great tip. Just had to add the line: httpWebRequest.Proxy = System.Net.WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy; before the using statement. Many thanks for the help.

Comment: @rbb please post that as an answer und use the green tick mark to mark this question as answered ;-)

Comment: @codesparkle Will do. As a new poster, must wait 7 hours before answering your own question. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks much to Darkey for the article. Adding in the line of code for DefaultWebProxy worked wonders. All I did was add the following line before the "using" statement:

httpWebRequest.Proxy = System.Net.WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;

before the using statement.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. Your code doesn't seem to be any `httpWebRequest` in your code.

Comment: @svick Not sure what to tell you except that it worked to set the default Proxy that a basic web request would use. Assuming that it just retrieved the proxy settings of the default browser, but could be wrong.